# Ideas for C# template function

Tags: c#, templates

So I am refactoring a library in C# which is basically a wrapper for some DLL. There is ton of functions in the wrapper which all share the same copy-and-paste boilerplate code. Below is an example, it is C# where *arguments* is pseudocode for eg. int arg1, bool arg2 etc.

```
public ReturnType foo(arguments)
    {
        if (!isOpen)
        {
           return ReturnType.RESULT_NOT_OPEN;
        }
        if (!Monitor.TryEnter(mutex, mutexTimeout))
        {
          return ReturnType.RESULT_LOCK_TIMEOUT;
           
        }
        
        ReturnType result;
        try { result = SomeFunctionFromDll(handle, arguments); }
        finally { Monitor.Exit(mutex); }
       
        return result;
    }
```

The DLL functions have different types of arguments but an identical signature as the C# wrapper, apart for the handle argument. It would be so neat to get rid of all this boilerplate. The dream scenario would be like

```
private ReturnType AllCommonBoilerPlate(arguments, dll_function_reference)
{
 // Do mutex, error check etc  
    dll_function_reference(handle, arguments); 
}

public ReturnType foo(arguments)  
   return AllCommonBoilerPlate(arguments, SomeFunctionFromDll);
```

It this concept feasible with C#? I tried playing around a bit with delegate functions but could not find a solution.

I see that I could put all the initial checks like isOpen and trying to obtain the mutex in a separate function, but that does not help too much. Also, that would obscure the mutex a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the concept is totally feasible. Hope this helps to give you an idea:

```
private T AllCommonBoilerPlate<T>(Func<T> dll_function_reference, object handle, object arguments)
    {
        if (!isOpen)
        {
            return ReturnType.RESULT_NOT_OPEN;
        }
        if (!Monitor.TryEnter(mutex, mutexTimeout))
        {
            return ReturnType.RESULT_LOCK_TIMEOUT;

        }

        T result;
        try { result = dll_function_reference(handle, arguments); }
        finally { Monitor.Exit(mutex); }

        return result;
    }

    public ReturnType foo(object arguments)
    {
        return AllCommonBoilerPlate<ReturnType>(() =>
            {
                return SomeFunctionFromDll(handle, arguments);
            },
            handle,
            arguments);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a start for me. I see that AllCommonBoilerPlate has to be a generic function and that we have to wrap the DLL function in a lambda. However, "arguments" is not a single argument but it multiple arguments with varying data types.  For instance DllFunctionA(handle, int, ushort), DllFunctionB(handle, uint, int) etc. This results in casting errors, e.g. cannot convert from uint to ushort. I think the compiler should be able to infer the correct casts somehow, as it is just integers, but I do not know how.

Comment: Ooh wait, now I see I can just add the types as as template arguments as AllCommonBoilerPlate<T1, T2>. Okey, this works!